# Problem with horizontal nav menu css in IE6

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I have a question. I have a horizontal navigation menu made by official css tutorial. Here is the CSS:

```
div.horizontal
{
width:700px;
height:30px;
margin:0 auto;
}
div.horizontal ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div.horizontal li
{
float:left;
}
div.horizontal a
{
display:block;
position:relative;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
padding-top:18px;
padding-bottom:0px;
}
div.horizontal a:link,div.horizontal a:visited
{

white-space: nowrap;
height: 40px;
line-height: 15px;
font-weight: normal;
font-size:12px;
overflow: hidden;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
z-index: 100;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
}
div.horizontal a:hover,div.horizontal a:active
{
    background-image:url(images/horiz-menu-active.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
color:#FFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="horizontal">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="contacts.php">За контакти</a></li>
                <li><a href="comments.php">Мнения и коментари</a></li>
                <li><a href="media_center.php">Медиа Център</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.php">Новини</a></li>
                <li><a style="border-right:2px #900 solid;" href="aboutus.php">За нас</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

In all browser includning IE7 and IE8 it appear normal as I want but in IE6 it's vertical. Please give mi some advise whath to do?

Live example here: [jsfiddle.net/uhRzR](http://jsfiddle.net/uhRzR)

Comment: Please also provide your HTML, or better yet make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example.

Comment: Do you really have to support IE6?

Comment: In my country most of the pipeople a computer illiterate. And are using the damn "blue icon" calling it the internet. So no comment :(

Comment: Aha, well damn! Is this country Bulgaria?

Comment: Yep. The our browser statistic is opposite to the world statistic

Comment: I know and sympathise with your situation. I lived there for a while, so I know exactly what it's like to have to support this decade old and outdated browser Let's see if we can help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way I can suggest you to fix this issue for ie6 is to add a fixed width for the `div.horizontal li`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uhRzR/2/ <- In this example I added width 100px.

---

An alternative solution is to use css hack for internet explorer adding `_width:0px;` for `div.horizontal li`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uhRzR/5/

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this part of your css

```
div.horizontal li
{
float:left;
}
div.horizontal a
{
display:block;
position:relative;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
padding-top:18px;
padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

with this

```
div.horizontal li
{
display:inline;
}
div.horizontal a
{
padding:18px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```